# SQL Server: I wonder what syntax error is near else

Tags: sql-server

I'm tring to create a procedure. And when I set @age after setting @flag, something is wrong. But either I tried to delete  `set @age` or `set @flag` it would work.

error:there is a syntax error near else

I wonder what caused this. Thanks for help.

```
select * from sc
if exists(select *
                    from sysobjects
                    where name='pro5' and type ='P')
    drop procedure pro5
go

create procedure pro5 @stuNo char(10),@flag int output
as 
declare @age int
begin
        set @age=0
        set @flag=1
        if exists(select *
                  from sc
                  where sno=@stuNo)
            set @flag=0
            set @age=0
        else
                delete 
                from student
                where sno=@stuNO

end
return @age
go

declare @flag int
exec pro5 '991102',@flag output
if @flag=1
    print 'success'
else
    print 'failure'
```

Comment: You need a `begin` and `end` for your `IF`

Comment: You don't *need* a `BEGIN` and `END` if you use an `IF`, @Stu , however, if you don't, it is inferred that the next line is what is be run when resolve to `TRUE`; the op has 2 lies, hence why they need a `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: That's precisely what I mean, the OP has two lines and an `else` so in this case it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed syntax a bit:

```sql
create procedure pro5 (
   @stuNo char(10),
   @flag int output
)
as 

begin
  declare @age int
        set @age=0
        set @flag=1
        if exists(select *
                  from sc
                  where sno=@stuNo)
          begin
            set @flag=0
            set @age=0
           end
        else
                delete 
                from student
                where sno=@stuNO

return @age
end

go

declare @flag int
exec pro5 '991102',@flag output
if @flag=1
    print 'success'
else
    print 'failure'
```

Comment: This will still generate the same error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36978427ff45fa11955f08ca44a6026f)

Comment: I fixed him good

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `begin` and `end` around all lines in your `if` statement which by default only assumes a single line belongs to the "if" block:

```
if exists(select * from sc where sno=@stuNo)
begin
    set @flag=0
    set @age=0
end
else
    delete 
    from student
    where sno=@stuNO
```

However you could simplify a little since you don't need to also set `age` which is already 0. I'm assuming you actualy might need to set @age to `1` and this is a cut-down example of your code and you can amend as required:

```
create procedure pro5 @stuNo char(10), @flag int output
as 
declare @age int = 0;
    
if exists(select * from sc where sno = @stuNo)
  set @flag = 0
else
begin
  delete from student where sno = @stuNO;
  set @flag = 1;
end

return @age;
```